# how to access child instances

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include<stdio.h>

class parent
{
public:
    parent()
    {
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    child()
    {
    }
};

class master
{
public:
    void view(parent a)
    {
        printf("view parent instances");
    }
    void view(child b)
    {
        printf("view child instances");
    }
};

int main()
{
    parent *ptr;
    master mymaster;

    ptr = new child;

    mymaster.view(*ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

output : "view parent instances"
I create a pointer from parent class. then I declared that pointer as child type. when i run mymaster.view(*ptr); , this always go to first view function (void view(parent a)), how to make it go to (void view(child b)). thankyou

Answer (score 4):

With a little refactoring and a slightly different approach, you could use `virtual` functions. This enables the function from derived classes to be used when called using a pointer like below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

class parent
{
public:
    parent()
    {
    }
    virtual void view()
    {
      printf("View parent");
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    child()
    {
    }
    virtual void view()
    {
      printf("View child");
    }
};

class master
{
public:
    void view(parent *a)
    {
        a->view();
    }
};

int main()
{
    parent *ptr;
    master mymaster;
    ptr = new child;
    mymaster.view(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This will output *"View child"*. The same code without the `virtual` keywords will output *"View parent"*. Note that the keyword only needs to be in the parent class, but is often used in the derived classes too for clarity.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) on virtual functions explains the situation pretty well:

> Virtual functions are resolved 'late'. If the function in question is
>   'virtual' in the base class, the most-derived class's implementation
>   of the function is called according to the actual type of the object
>   referred to, regardless of the declared type of the pointer or
>   reference. If it is not 'virtual', the method is resolved 'early' and
>   the function called is selected according to the declared type of the
>   pointer or reference.

Since the actual type of the object here is a **child**, the virtual function makes sure that the **child**'s functionality is called even though the pointer is of **parent** type.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `*(parent*)` is `parent`, so the method that gets called is `view(parent)`. If you want to invoke `view(child)`, you need to cast the pointer to a `child*` before passing it in, however...

You're using OOP backwards. You don't define multiple methods that know how to consume each specific type of sub-class, you define one method that can respect the contract provided by the parent class, and the sub-classes do their own thing internally.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is a pointer to a `parent` object.
If you want to have the `view(child)` function called, you need to pass a `child` object to the function call.

Alternatively, you can cast it to a `child` pointer

```
mymaster.view(*(child*)ptr);
```

but you're likely to end up with all kinds of other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler decides the matching method according to the best choice.

The compiler sees that the variable is of type `parent`, so it calls the matching method.